# traefik subfolder: links are broken

Tags: docker, traefik

I try to migrate a few intranet sites (wordpress, wiki, others) in our company to docker. The services for itself are working properly after the migration. I can connect to the services with http://hostname:8081, http://hostname:8082 and so on.

Now I want to use traefik to access to the services via http://hostname/servicename. That works principally with PathPrefixStrip.

But when I try to access a service via http://hostname/service, then all links (css, javascript, ...) inside of my service's sources are failing, because they assume to run on root itself, and not in a subfolder called service. How can I manage that problem?

Answer (score -1):

Links are generated by wordpress, not Traefik. You need to configure wordpress to use the new URL with the new path to generate links.

I would advise using `PathPrefix` instead of `PathPrefixStrip` in this case.

https://tanyanam.com/2015/07/13/setting-up-wordpress-behind-reverse-proxy/